# How can I customize documents for each user in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database which must contain a lot of stories, so a lot of documents, and these stories must be written by users themselves . How can I link between documents and users? I know that every document has a unique ID so are users since I use Firebase Authentication but now I try to make documents for each user, so everyone of them can write and edit only to their document . And when they click on " My Stories " in the app for example only his/her stories will show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have separate collections for `users` and `stories`. In each document in the `stories` collection, make sure you have the UID (from Firebase Auth) of the user who has created that.

So a story document may look like:

```
{
  storyID: "",
  userID: "userUID"
  ...restOfTheFields
}
```

To get stories of a specific user, you can run the following query:

```
db.collection("stories")
        .whereEqualTo("userID", uidOfCurrentUser)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

That way you get the document IDs of all the stories of that user as well.

To ensure a user can read their own stories only, you can set the security rules as follows:

```
match /stories/{storyId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
    }
```

Alternatively you can use sub-collections but in case any day you need to query stories based on story ID and you don't know the user ID, having a top level collection helps.

Comment: It worked like magic thanks Sir. But is it ok to make a field inside Stories Collection called " UserID" instead of creating " Users " Collection . That's way I'll guarantee a user Id will be added with every story. What's your opinion? I'm totally new to FireStore stuff to be honest and I'm afraid of number of reads/writes because they charge you on that..

Comment: @NaFa usually in "users" collection you would store user specific information such as email and name which should be private to them. "stories" collection will have stories created by all the users. It's pretty normal and 1 read means 1 document (1 story in this case). That aren't much expensive and you also have a generous free quota.

Comment: Do I have to create a collection for users if I'm using Firebase Authentication ? I mean it's already integrated with Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Store stories inside the `subcollection` of the user `doc`

```
{
id:<autogenerated / authid>
name: author_name
stories: <subcollection>
}
```

that way you can query `subcollection` docs based on author `id` and perform actions like read/update without worrying about other authors' stories.

Note that firestore queries are shallow by nature means when you fetch author `doc`, subcollection won't be included. you need to fetch `subcollection` separately.